# c++ ifstream printing last item in file twice

Tags: c++, ifstream

I want to read the data from the file afile.dat and then print the data to the screen. The content of the file is as follows:

```
Max
20
```

In order to print the two items to the screen I wrote the following C++ program:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main () 
{

   char data[100];

   ifstream infile; 
   infile.open("afile.dat"); 

   cout << "Reading from the file" << endl; 

   while(infile){   
        infile >> data;
         cout << data << endl;  
   }

   infile.close();

   return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Max
20
20
```

Why is "20" printed twice?

Comment: `while(infile >> data)`  Test for errors on the read, because the error won't be set until after you've performed a bad read and used the incorrect data.

Comment: to expand on @RetiredNinja, the final call to `infile >> data` fails to read a value for `data` but it's stell set from the last time.  That failure then triggers the `while(infile)` to fail on the _next_ iteration.

Comment: You should not loop on the state of the file, but on the return value of a read operation. See https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof for why.

Comment: Exact same issue, only without explicitly writing `.eof()`.

Comment: You could try `while(!infile.eof())`

Comment: @ppham27 No. Even reading the title of the dupe would have told that's not correct.

Comment: @BaummitAugen It does actually work in this case as tested on my local machine, but in general, it's clear that you're right.